# Make units visible when mousing into textbox or combobox

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, textbox, userform

[image]I have a userform that requires input into various textboxes and comboboxes. The inputs are for measurements and have units associated with them. I want the userform to display which units are expected to be used when you click into each specific text/combobox.

Currently, my code works for textboxes but does not recognize comboboxes. Here is my code.

```
Private Sub TextboxActions_MouseUp(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
If InStr(1, TextboxActions.Name, "OD") > 0 Then
    UserForm1.inUnit.Visible = True
    UserForm1.mmUnit.Visible = False
    UserForm1.eaUnit.Visible = False

ElseIf InStr(1, TextboxActions.Name, "CE") > 0 Then
    UserForm1.inUnit.Visible = False
    UserForm1.mmUnit.Visible = True
    UserForm1.eaUnit.Visible = False

Else
    UserForm1.inUnit.Visible = False
    UserForm1.mmUnit.Visible = False
    UserForm1.eaUnit.Visible = True
End If
End Sub
```

Using this, when the user clicks a textbox it will display the units in, mm, or ea. I want this to be the case for comboboxes as well, but currently nothing happens when clicking into a combobox.

Comment: What are inUnit, mmUnit, eaUnit?  Are they labels beside the textboxes ?  If so why not have one label called Units, and just change the caption?

Comment: Correct--inUnit, mmUnit, and eaUnit are the names of the label. The label appears in only one place at the bottom of the userform, not right beside each textbox.

Answer (score 2):

First, I would use `Enter` event instead of `Mouse up` event, so same thing will happen when you Tab into the control.  For each control's `Enter` event simply call this ShowUnit function and feed it the controls name.

```
Private Sub CE2_Enter()
    Call ShowUnit(CE2)
End Sub

Private Sub OD1_Enter()
    Call ShowUnit(OD1)
End Sub

Private Sub ShowUnit(ByRef oControl As Control)
    If InStr(1, oControl.Name, "OD") > 0 Then
        UserForm1.inUnit.Visible = True
        UserForm1.mmUnit.Visible = False
        UserForm1.eaUnit.Visible = False

    ElseIf InStr(1, oControl.Name, "CE") > 0 Then
        UserForm1.inUnit.Visible = False
        UserForm1.mmUnit.Visible = True
        UserForm1.eaUnit.Visible = False

    Else
        UserForm1.inUnit.Visible = False
        UserForm1.mmUnit.Visible = False
        UserForm1.eaUnit.Visible = True
    End If
End Sub
```

edit: Changed names of controls to illustrate how to use the code and returned "OD" and "CE" in the `instr()` functions from my test values.

For additional clarification see the image below to see what's going on.  The Blue is how you can use the GUI to ensure you are referencing the Controls Event.  Red is indicating that we pass the full Control to the ShowUnit Function.  The Purple is showing that we take are reading the Controls Name property to search for "OD" or "CE"  note that these are case sensitive without using `instr(1, UCASE(oControl.Name), "OD") > 0`, so if your controls name is odSomeName it won't make the inUnit label visible.

[image]

Comment: this one didn't work for me. I changed "Text" back to "OD" and "Combo" back to "CE" and tried clicking into the textboxes and comboboxes but now neither one displays the units. I'm wondering if I need to rename some objects to get this work?

Comment: Are you using ComboBox1 and TextBox1 as names for your boxes? In the userform I am making there are about 50 different text and comboboxes. I am trying to make a generic function that will display EA, IN, or mm depending if the name of the box contains "CE" or "OD" in it. Hope that clarifies

Comment: @DaveFriesen I've updated my answer for additional clarification.  As well as changed my test values from Textbox1 & ComboBox1 to OD1 and CE2

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. If I'm understanding correctly does this mean that I need a new sub for each combo/text box in my userform with the name of that box in the subject of the sub?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  You will need to direct each controls `Enter` event to the `ShowUnit` procedure.  I don't believe there's a way to override all control's Enter Events in VBA.

Comment: Also, does the name of the sub need to be the textbox's name_Enter()? as in, if my textbox is named LCE2, I want my sub named 
`LCE2_Enter()
Call ShowUnit(LCE2)
End sub`

Is that right?
Looks like this is not working unfortunately

Comment: Yes, that looks correct with the naming of the event.  Use the dropdowns at the top of the screen, boxed in blue in my image.  Select your control in the first one then Enter in the second one.  Add the line and put a break point on the `Call ShowUnit(LCE2)` and see if when you click into LCE2 it stops on this line.  If it does then the event is triggering properly.  If it does not then the event is not triggered or associated with the right control.

Comment: I added an image to show you what I see on my screen. I don't seem to have the controls in the left dropdown menu. The right drop down has all the subs like LCE2_Enter etc in it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179047/discussion-between-josephc-and-dave-friesen).

Comment: Wow, what a silly mistake I was making. I had the code in a separate module and not in the userform code. Yikes. So far it seems to be working but will update when done.

Answer (score 2):

Using 3 `Enter()` events worked for me:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Enter()

UserForm1.Label1.Visible = True
UserForm1.Label2.Visible = False
UserForm1.Label3.Visible = False

End Sub
Private Sub ComboBox2_Enter()

UserForm1.Label1.Visible = False
UserForm1.Label2.Visible = True
UserForm1.Label3.Visible = False

End Sub
Private Sub ComboBox3_Enter()

UserForm1.Label1.Visible = False
UserForm1.Label2.Visible = False
UserForm1.Label3.Visible = True

End Sub
```

Example of clicking in ComboBoxes (In top Userform `ComboBox1` is active, in second Userform `ComboBox3` is active, etc.)

[image: img]

Comment: Using this method do I need a new sub for each combo/text box? My userform has about 50 boxes. I am trying to make a function that will display EA, IN, or mm (text objects in the userform) depending if the name of the box contains "CE" or "OD" in it. Hope that clarifies

Comment: Let me edit my answer tomorrow - this changes the situation a bit. You'll probably need one `Userform` level event.

Comment: After looking at some options I think you're best off with an enter event for each combobox... The other workaround solutions just look too convoluted. Sorry I can't help any further.